# ComponentResolutionException after upgrading to Castle 3.0

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, castle

I've just upgraded a solution from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4
In the same time, I've upgraded all external libraries to the latest version, so Castle is now upgraded from 2.5.2 to v3.0

I've some code that register db access that throw now an Exception when I try to resolve:

> [Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException] {"Could not obtain
>   scope for component DF.MailFlowAdapter. This is most likely either a
>   bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped
>   component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component
>   outside of web request
>   etc)"}    Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException

The component is registered this way:

```
Container
    .AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
    .AddFacility<DataAccessAdapterFacility>()
    .Register(Component
        .For<SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.IDataAccessAdapter>()
        .ImplementedBy<MailFlowAdapter>()
        .LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation())
```

The problem comes from the PerWcfOperation LifeStyle, but I don't know why: The project is a WCF project and the component is resolved when calling a WCF method.
This registration is working fine in the branch that use Castle 2.5.

The exception is thrown when Validating the wcf login/pwd (in a IAuthorizationPolicy that use a UserNamePasswordValidator), because I resolve an IDataAccessAdapter (to check login/pwd in the db).

Other piece of information:

The DataAccessAdapterFacility is an old code that register a component activator, I had to slightly change de code because model.Service changed to model.Services:

```
void Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
{
    foreach (var service in model.Services)
    {
        if (service == typeof(SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.IDataAccessAdapter))
        {
            model.CustomComponentActivator = typeof(DataAccessAdapterActivator);
        }
    }
}
```

And the DataAccessAdapterActivator has in charge to create the object using a connection string in the config file:

```
protected override object InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
{
    var connectionString = string.Empty;
    if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"] != null)
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ConnectionString;
    return new MailFlowAdapter(connectionString);
}
```

I think the code with DataAccessAdapterFacility/DataAccessAdapterActivator could be simplify using Factory but it's not the question here :)

So does someone have an idea on why I can't use PerWcfOperation lifestyle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Let's resume my discussion with Craig Neuwirt on the castle mailing list:

- The behaviour has changed,  in v2.5 is was falling back on a
  transient lifestyle. But as it was not consistent (No info on when
  the component was PerWcfOperation and when it was Transient) this has
  been removed.
- It's possible to do the same using a custom lifestyle scope accessor

I'll not post my code here as it's trivial once you've read how the Hybrid lifestyle are done in the [castlecontrib](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles) project

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe an OperationContext.Current is available at the point where a custom UserNamePasswordValidator is called.  Is it possible to use another lifestyle for that component?